# How to specify Scala and SBT version for publish-local?

Tags: sbt

I'm developing a SBT compiler plugin with Scala 2.9.2 and SBT 0.12.0.

My project uses the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "myplugin"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

organization := "com.my.org"

sbtVersion := "0.12.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.2"
```

After writing the plugin I'm publishing it to my local Ivy repository using `publish-local` that publishes to `~\.ivy2\local\com.my.org\myplugin\0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

To test the plugin, I've created a simple "Hello-World" project and added the following  `project/build.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.my.org" %% "myplugin" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

When trying to load the project using `sbt` I get an `Unresolved Dependency` error for that plugin. I noticed that `sbt` looks for the plugin in `~\.ivy2\local\com.my.org\myplugin\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

My question is how do I correct the configuration to include the Scala and SBT versions? Or, alternately, how do I resolve the plugin resolution to look in the right place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say all you're missing is the setting `sbtPlugin := true` in your plug-in's `build.sbt`. This should make your plug-in publish correctly.